# Compiling Kernel and keeping ZFS

Tags: kernel, zfs

Whenever I compile a custom kernel, I seem to lose ZFS support.

I followed the instructions located here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel. However, even though I start with kernel 4.4.0-generic, when I follow those instructions, I somehow end up with 4.4.44 - (odd, because even the source directory explicitly is listed as "linux-4.4.0").

I will install the newly created deb packages and reboot. Then I will issue `apt install zfs` which seems to work fine but `modprobe zfs` complains that zfs was not found. It is not located anywhere in /lib/modules/4.4.44/. I have zfs.ko for earlier versions of the kernel, but not 4.4.44.

So, while the kernel compiles and installs just fine, I lose ZFS support. Is there a way to have both?

Answer (score 0):

Enable ZFS options this way...

The easy way to start with a custom kernel is to use an old, working configuration file from any distribution. A copy of the configuration file is saved for you in /boot. Simply copy the configuration, use `make oldconfig` to generate a .config file using the old as a template. You will be asked to answer any questions regarding new features and are safe using the defaults (hit the enter key). It is the prudent to review the configuration changes with `make menuconfig`.

```
cp /boot/config-4.4.0-generic ~/src/linux-4.4.0/.config
make oldconfig
make menuconfig
```

source: http://bodhizazen.com/Tutorials/kernel

Comment: If my answer was helpful, please **vote** by clicking the grey up-arrow icon in the upper-left of my answer, and **accept** my answer by clicking the grey checkmark icon in the upper-left of my answer. Thanks!